# C# Open listView Item from treeView item location

Tags: c#, listview, treeview

I'm needing a way to allow the files that are displayed in the `ListView` to be opened. The Items In the `ListView` are displayed from the `TreeView`. Take a look at my code below to see in more detail.

**Code for this form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace OSTP
{
    public partial class User1FileExplorer : Form
    {
        public User1FileExplorer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateTreeView();
            this.treeView1.NodeMouseClick +=
    new TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.treeView1_NodeMouseClick);
        }

        private void User1FileExplorer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void PopulateTreeView()
        {
            TreeNode rootNode;

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\.OSTP\User1\Files\Documents");
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
                rootNode.Tag = info;
                GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
            }
        }

        private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs,
            TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
        {
            TreeNode aNode;
            DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
            {
                aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
                aNode.Tag = subDir;
                aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
                subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
                if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
                {
                    GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
                }
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
            ListViewItem item = null;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), 
             new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), 
             new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }

            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code I use a `TreeView` to select the directory for the files then the `ListView` to display the files inside of the directory.

I would like it so when the user double clicks the file in the `ListView` it opens. And when I say open I'm not meaning open a text file as such. So lets say the user double clicks text file 1 in the `ListView`, I would like it to show `User1TextFile1.cs`. This is because the text files are loaded into a text box.

I know this is a little complicated, so If I have missed anything please drop a comment.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

http://pastebin.com/BgVdLavL

**UPDATE2**

[image]

*When I add `MessageBox.Show("" + lvHti);`*

Comment: This is confusing although it may be very simple. So the user doubleclicks a filename and you want to, what? display the content? If it can be displayed in a TextBox or a RTB, well, there should be no other problem than maybe having the path as well as the filename. So why do you write _. And when I say open I'm not meaning open a text file as such._ And is `User1TextFile1.cs` the filename he clicked on? Besides the path you may want to check out how to access the double clicked item in a Listview: The simplest way is going for SelectedItems[0]..

Comment: I want it so when the user clicks one of the text files, any one of them they are taken to the User1TextFile1.cs form. I already have the User1TextFile1.cs set up to load different text files from the disk.

Comment: So where __is__ the problem? Maybe referencing the User1TextFile1-Form?  Keep a reference when opening it! Or opening it? Or loading the text? Give it a `public loadTextFile(string fileName) ` function.

Comment: All I need help with is detecting which item in the list view is selected, I can do the rest. I have everything else ready to be set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which `ListViewItem` was clicked or doubleclicked use the `MouseClick` or the `MouseDoubleClick` event.

Here you can either code simply:

```
ListViewItem lvItem = null;

if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    lvItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
```

provided the `ListView` has `MultiSelect = false`.

If you allow multiple selections you need to do a `HitTest` to find out where the user has clicked:

```
ListViewItem lvItem = null;

ListViewHitTestInfo lvHti = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
if (lvHti.Item != null) lvItem = lvHti.Item;
```

Now you can access the `Item` and/or its `SubItems` to process the choice.

Comment: This looks okay, but its not very well explained, im not sure how to implement the code properly. and yes my listview has MultiSelect = false

Comment: Which part is unclear??? You put the two lines above in the event I mentioned and then have the item you asked about.

Comment: I have implemented the code where I think it should be check the update patebin link

Comment: Yeah well, I thought you know what to do with the item?

Comment: Can you make it display the file link in a messagebox?

Comment: like this? `if (lvItem != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lvItem.Text, "You have clicked on file");
    }` You may need the Path as well. Stroring the FileInfo object in the Tag of the ListViewItems may be a good idea..: `item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1); item .Tag = file;`

Comment: ye im not getting this, sorry, all i can say is thank you for your help. if i make it work i'll get back to you.

Comment: Well,it works fine here. Note that HitTestInfo has many helpful fields that will tell you exactly what was hit.. An object rarely can be cast to string and show anything else than its class name.