# How to set icon to subitem of listview using c#?

Tags: c#

I have listview control. It's possible to choose imageindex from imagelist and set image to listview **item** but how can I set icon to listview **subitem**?

```
        listView1.Columns.Add("Objects");
        listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
        listviewitem = new ListViewItem("David", 1);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("John");
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
        listView1.View = View.Details;
```

I want to set image to subitem - named "John".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only have **one** image for a `ListViewItem` and it has to be with the main `ListViewItem` (i.e. with `SubItems[0]`.)

But you can change the display order, so you can display the image in any column.

```
listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 2;
```

[image]

**But**, of course you can also **owner-draw** the `ListView` and include images with **any number** of `SubItems`! This will take a few more lines of code (around a dozen) but it will allow you to style the `ListView` in pretty much any way you like..

Here is an example that has (random) images in all columns:

[image]

To get this result you need to..:

- Set `OwnerDraw = true` for the LV
- Set `UseItemStyleForSubItems = false` for all Items
- Code all three `Drawxxx` events.
- Decide on how to store the references to the 2nd (etc) image, since the `SubItem` class doesn't have an `ImageIndex`.

You can either use the `Tag` of the `SubItem` to hold the `ImageIndex` number or, if you don't need the `Text`, you can set the text so you can use it as index or even as `Key` into the `ImageList`.

Two of the events are simple:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

The third one is where you actually do some drawing:

```
    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Size sz = listView1.SmallImageList.ImageSize;
        int idx = 0;
        if (e.SubItem.Tag != null) idx = (int)e.SubItem.Tag;
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)listView1.SmallImageList.Images[idx];
        Rectangle rTgt = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location, sz);
        bool selected = e.ItemState.HasFlag(ListViewItemStates.Selected);
        // optionally show selection:
        if (selected ) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, e.Bounds);

        if (bmp != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, rTgt);

        // optionally draw text
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, listView1.Font,
                              selected  ? Brushes.White: Brushes.Black,
                              e.Bounds.X + sz.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 2);
    }
```

Of course you will want to restrict the drawing of images and maybe of Text to those columns you need.. Adding more checks should be simple..

Comment: For moving the image column around the one line in the answer is enough, provided you have set the item to be the image column. Do you want to dislay one or more images in each row?

Comment: Yes I want two images.

Comment: Can I make clickeventhandler for each subitems?

Comment: No, but you can code the `MouseClick` event and do a `HitTest` to see which if any of the SubItems was clicked. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566498/c-sharp-open-listview-item-from-treeview-item-location/35586331?s=1|0.3923#35586331)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154021/discussion-between-j-doe-and-taw).